# How to make this script run on realtime triggered by a message

Tags: python, telegram

I have this script to copy messages from one channel to another on Telegram via Python.
This currently will run once, copy all missing messages and then finish.
How can I modify this to either run at an interval or to run when a new message comes up in a channel?

I have other files that are utilized such as the API config files with the API key / channels etc.

Even if someone can help point me in the right direction I'll dive more. I'm not very familiar with Python.

```
import asyncio
import logging

from telethon.tl.patched import MessageService
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import FloodWaitError
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from settings import API_ID, API_HASH, forwards, get_forward, update_offset, STRING_SESSION


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

SENT_VIA = f'\n__Sent via__ `{str(__file__)}`'


def intify(string):
    try:
        return int(string)
    except:
        return string


async def forward_job():
    ''' the function that does the job  '''
    if STRING_SESSION:
        session = StringSession(STRING_SESSION)
    else:
        session = 'forwarder'

    async with TelegramClient(session, API_ID, API_HASH) as client:

        confirm = ''' IMPORTANT 
            Are you sure that your `config.ini` is correct ?

            You can run the `get_chat_info.py` script to confirm the `from` and `to`.

            Press [ENTER] to continue:
            '''

        input(confirm)

        error_occured = False
        for forward in forwards:
            from_chat, to_chat, offset = get_forward(forward)

            if not offset:
                offset = 0

            last_id = 0

            async for message in client.iter_messages(intify(from_chat), reverse=True, offset_id=offset):
                if isinstance(message, MessageService):
                    continue
                try:
                    await client.send_message(intify(to_chat), message)
                    last_id = str(message.id)
                    logging.info('forwarding message with id = %s', last_id)
                    update_offset(forward, last_id)
                    
                except FloodWaitError as fwe:
                    print(f'\n{fwe}\n\nRun the script again after some time. \
                        FloodWaitError Occured')
                    quit()
                except Exception as err:
                    logging.exception(err)
                    error_occured = True
                    continue

            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert forwards
    asyncio.run(forward_job())
```

Comment: Do you own both channels?

Comment: I'm using this on a combination of two channels I own and another set of two channel where I own one and my colleague owns the other

Comment: Anyway, you can use long polling. You fist save the datetime of your last fetched post, then check the channel for new posts. There is a new post if the post's datetime is greater than the last fetched post's datetime. Did you try it?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but telegram first fetches the last channel posts. If that is possible with telethon, you can check if the last message is already fetched without going through the whole channel posts.

Comment: I haven't looked at Long Polling yet thank you. Currently there is an "offset" saved for the last message and this is how it's looking for new messages but it only will look for that once I run the actual file. I don't know how to trigger that code to run when a new message is posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [Updates](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html) documentation. Using it, you'll be able to get a new message in your code.

Also you'll need to change how you handle

Will look something similar to:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


client = TelegramClient(session, API_ID, API_HASH)

database = {}
for forward in forwards
    from_chat, to_chat, offset = get_forward(forward)
    database[from_chat] = {"to_chat": to_chat, "offset": offset}


@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):    
    to_chat = database.get(event.chat_id)
    if to_chat:
        await client.send_message(to_chat, event.message)
        last_id = message.id
        database[event.chat_id] = last_id
        logging.info('forwarding message with id = %s', last_id)


client.start()

# TODO: do `iter_messages` initial or while script was not running

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Or if you want to call it periodically, you can either:

- wrap method with `iter_messages` in a loop

  ```py
  while True:
      # TODO:
      # do_iter_messages__and__forwarding()

      await asyncio.sleep(10)
  ```
- or call method with `iter_messages` again from that method after some delay

  ```py
  def do_iter_messages__and__forwarding():
      # TODO:
      # for message in client.iter_messages(...):
      #     do_message_forward(...)

      await asyncio.sleep(10)
      do_iter_messages__and__forwarding()
  ```